# How to find login name in SQL Server from a user_name of database

Tags: sql, sql-server, authentication

How can I find login name in SQL Server from a `user_name` of database using a stored procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example you can use the system functions

```
declare @uname sysname = 'dbo'; -- user name in question
SELECT suser_sname(user_sid(USER_ID(@uname))) as login
```